# RAID for a home PC

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, raid

I have a home PC with two identical physical drives (SATA), ASUS P5Q-EM motherboard and Windows 7. HDD 1 has two partitions `C:` and `D:`, Windows is installed on `C:` and everthing else is on `D:`.

Now the task is to organize some kind of RAID to mirror all data from HDD 1 to HDD 2 (at the moment HDD 2 is empty, no partitions), so HDD 2 is a backup copy of HDD 1.

I've never had chance before to work with RAID, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Whatever you choose to do, I'd advise against using any RAID that comes from the motherboard.

Answer (score 6):

RAID is not a Backup. If you want a backup try using [Windows Backup](http://www.neowin.net/news/main/09/01/18/windows-7-windows-backup-overview).

If you want a duplicate drive in case one drive fails, then you want RAID. Firs tyou have to figure out [what kind of RAID setup you want](https://superuser.com/questions/7683), but it sounds like you want a mirror (RAID-1).

The quick directions to setup a mirror: Open Computer management, Storage->Disk management. Right click "Disk 0" and Convert to Dynamic. Do the same for the other disk. Right click your "C:" dirve and click "Add Mirror", follow the directions. It will take a little while to fully synch, but you can use the computer while it's working.

Comment: Did not know you could do that! +1