# Windows7 Create Striped volume

Tags: windows-7, raid, software-raid

I'm trying to raid0 a data partition on two disks in Windows7 Pro 64bit.

Both drives are identical, partition scheme is identical, I have converted them to dynamic disks.
But all the raid options in disk management are disabled.
Does Win7 Pro not support raid? Then why does it let you create dynamic disks?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/7683/which-software-raid-modes-does-each-version-of-windows-7-support

Comment: Do the partitions already exist, or do you have free space where this spanned volume will be?

Comment: @Zoredache - thanks, it was really a 'why doesn't this work?' question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to click on the non-boot drive first and create striped volume on that, then add the first drive to the set.

edit - leaving this here for the search engine