# How to create a Software RAID1 in Windows 7 Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, raid-1, diskpart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which software raid modes does each version of Windows 7 support?](https://superuser.com/questions/7683/which-software-raid-modes-does-each-version-of-windows-7-support)

Using the built in `DISKPART` program, or Disk Management, or anything else native to Windows 7, is there a way to build a mirrored volume in Windows 7 **Home Premium**? I have found resources for Pro and Ultimate, but I'm looking for a way to do it with Home Premium.

One attempt I had was to boot off of a Windows 7 Pro CD, and use the Command Prompt, and `DISKPART` to create a mirror (`CREATE MIRROR DISK=0,1 SIZE=xxx`), assign a letter (`ASSIGN LETTER=g`), and format it (`FORMAT /q g: /fs:ntfs`), but when I reboot back into Windows Home Premium, it doesn't show up in Computer, and under Disk Management, it simply reads `FAILED` for status.

Comment: Raid (dynamic disks) Not supported in Home edition.

Comment: @Moab I know it is officially not allowed, but I'm asking how to do it anyways, similar to how you can do it with Windows XP. I already mentioned that Pro and Ultimate can do it

Comment: You are asking to bypass the Windows Eula, which no one here will likely help with that.

Comment: proprietary OS <3