# How to setup RAID 5 in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, raid-5

How do I setup RAID 5 for Windows 7?

I tried it before without success. Is there third -party software or something that's required?

When I try to click on RAID 5:

[image]

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What did you try before?

Comment: @Insane Hey insane. thanks for fast comment first of all.
I have three partition of 25gb three of them mbr 
when i right click on one of the disks to do RAID 5 , it's does not let me click on it.

Comment: @Insane Edit my post .. check it out.

Comment: You can try it using diskpart from **cmd** full details: http://m.windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-use-diskpart-create-raid-5-set

Comment: @RACING121 thanks ! but tried already. "The command you selected is not available with this version of Windows" 
From what i know , windows 7 do not support raid 5. i think there is a third-party software for it.

Comment: @Liron_b Software Raid-5 is not supported in Windows 7 - You will need Windows Server in order to use a Software Raid-5 like you are trying to do - If you want to Raid-5, you will have to boot into your Raid Controller, either on-board or externally installed, and setup Raid-5 that way - However, I believe you will have to wipe your machine in order to setup a Raid-5 from scratch, and you will need all identical drives for it to work

Comment: @MikeDiglio Please explain yourself more detail. 
I don't have any raid Controller , Only today i learned what is raid 0,1, and 5.

By the way , i'm using vmware workstatsion if it's change something

Comment: @Liron_b There are 2 different types of Raid'ing - Software and Hardware - Software Raid is when you use the Operating System to setup a Raid and have it controlled by Disk Management - Hardware Raid is when you use a Raid Controller, either PCI-E or on-board from your Motherboard - The Raid Controller will manage your raid and this is the only way, when on Windows 7, to setup a Raid 5 - You will have to lookup your model Motherboard to see if it supports Raiding, and if it does, you will have to boot into it and setup Raid-5, along with adjusting your BIOS settings

Comment: @MikeDiglio I'm really sorry, but i still didn't understand you clearly. maybe you have word/pdf/video on how to create raid 5 for windows 7 machine? 
How to add raid controller to virtual machine ?

Comment: @Liron_b Here is an article from pcworld in regards to the different raid setups and how to go about getting it setup properly - http://www.pcworld.com/article/2849289/supercharge-your-pcs-storage-with-a-raid-setup-everything-you-need-to-know.html

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 does not support creating a software-based RAID5.

The option is visible (although not selectable) because the same drive management console utility is used in Windows Server as well, which *does* support creating a software RAID5.

See this other SU question for more info:

[Which software raid modes does each version of Windows 7 support?](https://superuser.com/questions/7683/which-software-raid-modes-does-each-version-of-windows-7-support)

To accomplish RAID5 with Windows 7 you will need a hardware (or firmware) based RAID controller that supports RAID5; one which supplies drivers compatible with Windows 7.